# Raise django admin validation error from a custom view

Tags: django, django-admin

I've some custom views in django-admin linked to my change_form.
All works well, but now I'd want to raise a ValidationError from my custom views and consequently get the flash in django-admin that prints the msg of ValidationError, that is the same that occurs if I raise it in model.clean().

an example of custom view that I use:

```
@site.admin_view
def send_transaction_mail(request, obj_id, typ):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=obj_id)
    if typ == 'SHIPMENT':
        send_order_confirm(order)
    else:
        raise Exception("Something goes wrong sending transaction mail")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

is there a way? Thank you

Comment: ordine = [...] send_order_confirm(order). "order" is undefined no ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Ricola3D: right, was just a typo. Burhan: the question is, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood what you want well:

You have a view, by definition a public page. You want it to display an error message in the admin pages (by definition privates page) ? It's odd. But if you want so.

To display an error in the admin pages, use the [Django Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/). It's what is in use to display the yellow rows with errors/notifications on the top of the pages.

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.error(request, "Something goes wrong sending transaction mail");
```

Indeed, validation errors an only displayed with forms. And thus, they are to be raised only in the clean() method of a form, a formset, or a field.

Comment: He is stating that his intention is to create a custom view for the admin pages.